# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected lambda_1 to have 1 dimensions, but got array with shape (32, 1)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am currently implementing triplet network on cifar-10 dataset, with the final loss as cross_entropy or mean square errror, How ever i am being delayed by this error which have been a headache to me. Hope anyone out here could help me figure out what is causing this error.

```
   def triplet_loss(x):
    """The triplet loss is ||A - P|| - ||A - N|| + alpha, where ||.||
    is the Euclidean norm. Notice that this is not a loss function in the
    format expected by Keras, ie f(y_true, y_pred)."""
    anchor, positive, negative = x
    margin = K.constant(alpha)

    positive = K.sum(K.square(anchor - positive), axis=1)
    negative = K.sum(K.square(anchor - negative), axis=1)

    loss = K.maximum(positive - negative + margin, 0)

    return loss

   batch_size = 32

   base_model=embedding_model()
   input_1 = Input((imsize, imsize, channel))
   input_2 = Input((imsize, imsize, channel))
   input_3 = Input((imsize, imsize, channel))

   A = base_model(input_1)
   P = base_model(input_2)
   N = base_model(input_3)


   loss = Lambda(triplet_loss)([A,P,N])
   model = Model(inputs=[input_1, input_2, input_3], outputs=loss)
   model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(LR))

   # create the data generators
   train_generator = generate_triplets()
   test_generator = generate_triplets(test=True)


   H = model.fit_generator(train_generator,...)


error 
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected lambda_1 to have 1 dimensions, but got array with shape (32, 1)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you use for base_model, triplet_loss and the dimensions of your output label?

Comment: the base model is resnet 50, dimension of the cifar-10 (-1,32,32,3

Comment: Please include the code for triplet loss, since the error comes from that function. Most likely categorical_crossentropy expects rank 1 tensor (eg. (32,)) but you are outputting (32,1) in your triplet_loss. So you should reduce the dimensions with tf.squeeze and return that in triplet_loss.

Comment: i have included the triplet loss